# Breaker Tripping - Need advice on upgrade

Tags: electrical, circuit-breaker, electrical-panel, wire

I am in the processes of consolidating all of my home audio / networking equipment into a server rack I picked up recently. This will give me some flexibility of keeping it all together and make repairs / upgrades easier.

In this process, I have had to reset my 15amp breaker twice now (it tripped) due to the load the equipment is putting on it I am assuming.

These devices range from a home audio controller, amp, sub amps, Backup Power Supply, PC, etc.

Some rough numbers I came up with:

```
Switch 2.5 amp
Sub .118 amp x 4 = .472 amp
Amp 8.36 amp
PSU 2.72 amp
Total 14.052 amp
```

With just those few devices, I seem to be at 93% of the suggested 80% load.

While I am not quite done getting everything moved into the rack, its already pretty clear that I will need to run some dedicated circuits for this rack.

What recommendations would you have for this? Should I run two 15amp circuits just for this equipment and put the audio stuff on one and lower stuff on the other?

I will probably end up getting an electrician out to do it but wanting to get some feedback to know what to ask for.

**Update:**

This is everything I could find on this current circuit that had some type of power rating label:

Device  Power

- Switch  100-240 v  2.5 amp

  Sub Amp 120v  13w consumption

  Sub Amp 120v  13w consumption

  Sub Amp 120v  13w consumption

  Controller  120v 70w consumption

  Amp 120v 920w consumption

  NVR 100v-240v

  PSU 300 watts

  Fan 110v

  Fan 110v

  Fan 110v

  Fan 110v

  Dell Tower  3.3 amp

  Apple Airplay Express   0.2 amp

  Modem   .75 amp

  Router  2.5 amp

  POE Injector    2.5 amp

  Cat Switch  1.5 amp

  Monitor 1.2 amp

  Monitor 1.2 amp

  Monitor 1.2 amp

  Monitor .7a

  TV  83 w consumption

  Gramofon    1amp

  Henge Dock (MacBook Pro)    127W 100-240V Power Supply

  Scentsy Candle Warmer   25 watts

  Digital Radio

  Alarm System Panel

  Lights

  Outlets

Comment: What other rooms, receptacles and fixed loads are also on that same circuit?  How are you arriving at those amp numbers? Are you seeing a difference between watts and VA?

Comment: Many of the devices listed the power consumption on the back of them, the amp for example was 920w consumed. Threw numbers into a calculator and got a very rough estimate. The above example is really more like 7.6. The other loads are things like a PC, Modem, Router, monitors, TV etc. Its a living space that this same circuit is on. I don't have any meters to get these exact numbers but my tests have been turning on one piece of equipment at a time and usually once more than half of the devices are on for a little while, it will trip.

Comment: @Harper The rest of the circuit is just outlets that have nothing plugged in. The above for-mentioned  devices are currently the only items that are drawing power. The current breaker is a single pole 15amp.

Comment: Have you considered running all the gear on 240V?

Comment: yeah, it's that other stuff.  Cheap PCs with their "850 watt" power supplies are 1200W/10A.  Modem and router are tiny, their stats are on their wall-wart.  Monitors and TVs are typically under 1A.   Do you have a laser printer?  Please get the nameplate loads for all of them, and edit those into your question.  And stop testing like that, you must not *provoke* breaker trips.  When you have a breaker trip, turn everything off for 30 minutes to let the wires in your walls cool.

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel - I haven't really. My box is rated for 220 and I think with all the breakers so far its at 340. Wasn't sure how a jump up to a 220 would impact the main that's already in there.

Comment: @Harper - Updated with all of the power labels I was able to find on the circuit that will occasionally trip. And my "method" was purely used to find out if there was a single faulty device that was causing this to happen, maybe something was shorting out that I could just replace and this whole mess would be gone. However, during that time, it was always random devices that this happened with. I did give things a cool down period before turning it all back on.

Comment: At 14 out of 15 amps the circuit is loaded slightly higher than it really should be.  At the end of the day tho you have a weak breaker, replace it with an exact replacement and be done with this issue.

Comment: If nothing else, as you're running that many power cords, invest in a high-grade PDU with an amp display on it.  Many UPSes will also show amperage draw.

Comment: Yeah, when you're doing new circuit, a 220V one is the best idea ever. It will save you some efficiency on the devices that can use it at half the amperage. It must be a brand new circuit. Old 110V one will still be necessary to support devices that are not multivoltage.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest the high-end audio be on a separate circuit than power supplies. I would run 2 20 amp circuits to this location. By separating the audio equipment from the power supplys you may avoid some electrical noise caused by harmonics that most powersupplys generate. Just my 2cents worth...

Answer (score 0):

Have the electrician come out and put a amp meter on the circuit with all equipment on and maxed out. That will give you the tru load and you can base your circuit determination based on that. Without looking at it I would suggest 2 - 2o amp 120v individual circuits. Most electronics are minimal in power consumption.